# What is a "payment SIM"?

Tags: nfc, tap-to-pay

In the settings for NFC I can enable purchases even if my phone is unlocked - if I have a payment SIM.

- What is a payment SIM?
- Who are providing them (is it banks, isp, super markets...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A payment SIM is a special, secure SIM card that allows you to make payments using NFC (knows as "Tap to pay"). The SIM card is issued by your carrier and linked to your debit or credit card, which is then automatically charged as you use your phone for payments.

For more information, see the official [Wallet FAQ](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/how-to/wp8/apps/wallet-faq), in the "What is Tap to pay, and how do I use it?" section.